# Not able to bring in front the frames in Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010, word-2003

I have similar doucment in Word 2003 and Word 2010 and all the styles been imported to Word 2010 document.

In Word 2003 I have a frame and document with two columns and a seperator line as shown below. The frame is on top of the line.
[image]

Similar to Word 2010 I got a frame on a document with two columns with a seperator but the seperator line is visible in the frame.
[image]

How can I make the Word 2010 frame similar to Word 2003 frame? This is a silly question but it is really annoying for me and I have this problem for the last 3 months open.

I would really appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shading fill color was set to white and it worked after setting shading fill color to white in Word 2010 for the frame.

Closing my own question